# Django : calling custom methods while User signup

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an App in Django, which requires a pre-defined method to be called at the time of new user registration/signup. Any idea if there is an app like django-registration or django-userena which allows calling such methods without any hacking in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [Django Signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). Then you can hook into the save method on a new user model.

Comment: django-registration ships with such a signal: http://docs.b-list.org/django-registration/0.8/signals.html#registration.signals.user_registered

Comment: @Arie - Frankly I haven't treid django-registration, since it hasn't been updated for more than a year. A lot has changed in django since then.

Comment: Even userena has custom signals for signup etc. Perfectly suited for my purpose.